# como puedo realizar una consulta dependiendo el valor de combobox

Tags: c#, combobox

utilizo este codigo(C#) para cargar los datos de una tabla(clientes) en un combobox y asi seleccionar el cliente pero como no todos los clientes pertenecen al mismo sector quiero hacer un filtro en donde desde otro combobox seleccione el sector y se modifique el combobox de clientes pero no se como indicarle que tome el valor en la parte de

```
sector=SqlDataAdapter adaptador = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT Nombre_c FROM clientes_i WHERE status_c = 'a' and Sector = ComboBox2.text ", CONEXION)
```

*el combobox de sectores tambien los cargo de la misma manera*

```
CONEXION.Open();
SqlDataAdapter adaptador = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT Nombre_c FROM clientes_i WHERE status_c = 'a' and Sector = ComboBox2.text ", CONEXION); DataSet ds = new DataSet();
adaptador.Fill(ds);
cmb_clientes.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
cmb_clientes.ValueMember = ds.Tables[0].Columns[0].ToString();
cmb_clientes.DisplayMember = ds.Tables[0].Columns[0].ToString();
CONEXION.Close();
```

Comment: and Sector = ComboBox2.text... eso estaria correcto, pero no podes meter el valor dentro de la cadena... no? por lo menos deberias concatenarla...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

para ingresar el valor de un textbox o comboBox se utiliza de la sigueinte manera:

```
'" + cmb_cliente.Text + "'
```

para que quede asi ya dentro de la consulta:

```
SqlDataAdapter adaptador = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT Nombre_c FROM clientes_i WHERE status_c = 'a' and Sector = '" + cmb_cliente.Text + "' ", CONEXION);
```